# How Call function from Controller which runs in background

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc

so i have this function controller where I create Users 
after the Users are created in Bulk, 
i want to send SMS/Email confirmation. 
But the email sms process makes it slow. (as i am using third party to send sms, i am not able to do bulk sms's)
Thus i want it so that once its has created the users it returns the UI (model) but still other thread works on 
sending sms/emails function. 
Please help. Thanks a lot

eg:

```
public async Task<AjaxReturn> ImportUsers(Users[] users)
{
  //there are lot of checks here which i have removed for showing 
  //save all the users at a time 
  var saved = await _accserver.SaveBulkUser(applicationUsers, userInfo.AccountId);

  //this below method i want to call but dont want to wait till its finish,
  // I want it to continue sending sms/emails
  SendUserConfirmation(goesAllsavedUsersHere);

  return AjaxReturnHelper.GetAjaxReturn(!isAllSaved) ? ResultTypes.Error : ResultTypes.Success);
}

private async void SendUserConfirmation(UsersListhere)
{
  foreach(var user in userlist)
  {
    await _messageservice.sendsms(.....);

    await _messageservice.sendemail(.....);
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question you've asked, but it might speed things up: don't await in the loop, add the resultant `Task` objects to a list and await them all at once with `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` where `tasks` is your list.

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions:

Don't use `async void`, you should use `async Task`.

Change `foreach(var user in userlist)` to `Parallel.ForEach(...)` because these calls can be async

Use callback function and send a notification via SignalR to WebUI then show a message

```
public async Task<AjaxReturn> ImportUsers(Users[] users)
{
    //there are lot of checks here which i have removed for showing 
    //save all the users at a time 
    var saved = await _accserver.SaveBulkUser(applicationUsers, userInfo.AccountId);

    //this below method i want to call but dont want to wait till its finish,
    // I want it to continue sending sms/emails
    SendUserConfirmation(goesAllsavedUsersHere, () =>
    {
        // do something here
        // you can try to call a SignalR request to UI and UI shows a message
    });

    return AjaxReturnHelper.GetAjaxReturn(!isAllSaved) ? ResultTypes.Error : ResultTypes.Success);
}

private async Task SendUserConfirmation(UsersListhere, Action doSomethingsAfterSendUserConfirmation)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(userlist, async (user) =>
    {
        await _messageservice.sendsms(.....);

        await _messageservice.sendemail(.....);
    });

    doSomethingsAfterSendUserConfirmation();
}
```